# add video and image with package imagepicker from one button flutter

Tags: flutter

with the package [ImagePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) I can easily pick an image or video, but from the perspective of user experience, is it possible to pick an image and video from one button, I mean while taking picture, the camera can change the mode from image to video by the user, but from code side, we have to use two methods：

```
final XFile? video = await _picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera);
final XFile? photo = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
```

So please tell me how to let flutter or package automatically detect which mode(picture/video) current camera is, thanks a lot!

Comment: even i tried this but i can't find the solution, ping me if you got the solutions

Comment: Hi Lucky I found this package(https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/wechat_camera_picker), I will have a try if it works in my case.